# How can I concatenate words and integers in python?

Tags: python, string, printing, integer, concatenation

I am trying to get the coordinates for something, in the form "[x,y]". For one line, all of the y-values are 5, and the x-values are 50, 55, 60, etc. I am trying to get python to print the coordinates. I've gotten everything but the printing part -

```
for i in range(50,150):
    if (i%5 == 0):
        print '[' + int(i) + ',' + '5]';
```

I'm doing something wrong in the last line. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't automatically perform the conversions. You need to convert your numbers using `str()` and then print.

```
for i in range(50,150):
  if(i%5 == 0):
    print '[' + str(i) + ',' + '5]';
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a string. Don't call `int` on your integer; call `str`, to get a string representation of it:

```
print '[' + str(i) + ',' + '5]'
```

or let the string format method take care of type coercion for you:

```
print '[{0},5]'.format(i)
```

or just make a list and print that. It'll have a space you weren't printing, which may or may not be what you want:

```
print [i, 5]
```